# Using AbstractRoutingDataSource to dynamically change the database schema/catalog

Tags: java, database, spring, runtime, datasource

According to [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/), you can use the AbstractRoutingDataSource from Spring Framework to dynamically change the data source used by the application.

However, the data sources used are defined by configuration, instead of programmatically. Is there a way of configuring the data sources to be used at runtime?

How scalable is this solution, i.e., what are the limitations in number of data sources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have implemented this approach for 30 datasources and they are currently running in a Production environment without any issues. If you are using JPA you can have a look at my config:

[dynamic-datasource-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402835/reading-from-multiple-dbs-with-same-persistence-unit)

Comment: Is there any documentation for to use AbstractRoutingDataSource in spring boot framework?. If yes , can you please share the documentation or any tutorial? , I am using spring boot for developing microservices. also spring data JPA .

Comment: Same as @Jacob, I need to be linked with 6 datasources.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674412/multiple-data-sources-with-same-entity-and-repo/48675156#48675156.
And resources : http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html and https://rjbtechnology.com/blog/2017-01/discriminator-multitenancy-with-spring-and-hibernate-no-filters/.