# Spring Data JPA global filter clause which inherits for all repository methods

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We are developing a multi tenancy web application using Spring boot + Spring data JPA with hibernate.

Multi tenancy is achieved by having an Organization table, which is wired to almost every table as a foreign key. Which means every DB call (Spring Data repository query methods) will have to be checked with the organization id.

I need a way that, this "where organization_id = ?" check to be injected automatically for every query method. So that developers won't have to specifically bother about organization id checks.

Is this achievable from Spring Data JPA framework? What are the pros, cons of this approach?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from multiple Db's with same Persistence Unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402835/reading-from-multiple-dbs-with-same-persistence-unit)

Comment: I dont think it's a duplicate. I would also like to know a way to do something like that but without full blown multi tenacy.

Comment: Agree with Robert. It's not multiple Dbs. It's same Db with same persistance unit. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If your have a base class, say BaseEntity you can use @org.hibernate.annotations.Filter:

1. In BaseEntity:

   @FilterDef(name = "organizationFilter", parameters = @ParamDef( name="orgId", type="long" ))
   @Filter(name = "organizationFilter", condition = "lang_id=:orgId")
2. On initialization of a session (override JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()?):

   session.enableFilter("organizationFilter").setParameter("orgId", organization.getId());