# How to dynamically change database/catalog when using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Consider a situation where all client data is stored in its own database/catalog and all such databases are stored in a single RDBMS (client-data). Master data (e.g. clients, ...) is kept in another RDBMS (master-data). How can we dynamically access a particular database in client-data RDBMS by means of `JdbcTemplate`?

Defining `DataSource` for each database in client-data RDBMS and then dynamically select one as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960397/using-abstractroutingdatasource-to-dynamically-change-the-database-schema-catalo) is not an option for us since the databases are created and destroyed dynamically.

I would basically need something like JDBC's `Connection.setCatalog(String catalog)` but I have not found anything like that available in Spring `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the datasource with `DelegatingDataSource` to call `setCatalog()` in `getConnection()`.

Comment: Hm, probably some kind of wrapper could be the solution. Now the thing is how to propagate the respective catalog to such a wrapper. Anyway good point.

Comment: On jdbcTemplate creation: `new JdbcTemplate(new MyDelegatingDS(dataSource, "catalogName"));` something like that

Comment: Yes, sure, I meant in the context of a whole solution but it is out of the scope of the question itself. Anyway, don't you wanna summarize your comments as an answer? I think it deserves to be accepted since at the moment there is probably not a better solution than `DataSource` wrapper.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you could wrap the datasource with [`DelegatingDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html) to call `setCatalog()` in `getConnection()` and use the wrapped datasource on `JdbcTemplate` creation:

```
class MyDelegatingDS extends DelegatingDataSource {
  private final String catalogName;

  public MyDelegatingDS(final String catalogName, final DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
    this.catalogName = catalogName;
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    final Connection cnx = super.getConnection();
    cnx.setCatalog(this.catalogName);
    return cnx;
  }

  // maybe also override the other getConnection();
}

// then use like that: new JdbcTemplate(new MyDelegatingDS("catalogName", dataSource));
```

Comment: You may want to add a try/catch around cnx.setCatalog() and close the connection if an Exception occurs. Otherwise you will leak connections (for example if the catalog doesn't exist).

Answer (score 6):

You can access the `Connection` from `JdbcTemplate`:

`jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setCatalog(catalogName);`

You'll only have to make sure the database driver supports this functionality.

Comment: Yes, I can use this approach but I do not want to work with JDBC (`Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, ...) directly. It is useless to use `JdbcTemplate` this way. The thing is that I would like to use `JdbcTemplate`'s interface to access data.

Comment: @pgiecek: the point of using JdbcTemplate is to avoid the boiler plate code that you need when you use plain JDBC. If a solution is simple and easy using plain JDBC then why not use it? It can't get any simpler than calling `setCatalog()`

Comment: Yes, I agree. I like `JdbcTemplate` because, as you pointed out, it enables to avoid JDBC boiler plate code. And just because of a tiny connection adjustment, I do not want to use JDBC directly. I think that @RC's solution is a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setSchema(schemaName)
```

Was what I needed for switching schema using postgres. Props to @m3th0dman for putting me on the right track. I'm only adding this in case others find this answer searching for switching schema as I was.

Comment: I am trying the same but it is not working for me. I tried printing the schema before and after this statement, and they return the same result - public. Is there anything else you did to make it work?